# when group of vectors are linear independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i tried to solved with someone who helped me online(it was in a paid online tutoring and she isn't available now) a question about the linear dependent of two groups of vector and telling which of them is linear dependent or not.

she writed one group as a matrix and with zero column at the end like that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&-1&0\\ \:1&1&-2&0\\ \:1&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
 and began to reduce it until she got: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\ \:0&1&-3&0\\ \:0&0&-5&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

than she multiplied the third row in -1/5 in order to get 1 in the third entry of the last row in order to get it into REF and told that becuase she needed to multiply the row by -1/5 it means that the group is linearly dependent and when she began reducing the next group and got row of zeros she told me that the group is linearly independent..

isn't it the other way around? if a matrix can be put into REF form like that with the same numbers of variables and rows it means that the system have unique solution and that the vectors are linearly independent?. 
if i got it wrong can you also tell me with what exactly i got confused? i almost sure i actualy readed it in a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're perfectly right : the 3 first columns $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ of the matrix you wrote are linearly independent. This is exactly because the system whose augmented matrix is that you wrote has a unique solution, namely $(0,0,0)$, which means that :

If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in\Bbb R$ are such that $\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2 + \alpha_3 v_3 =0$ then the $\alpha_i$'s are all zero : this is precisely the definition of linear independence.

Comment: if the columns are linear independent it means that the rows and the entire matrix is independent?. cause in the original question there was two groups of vectors: 1){u+3v-w , u+v-3w , v+w} and 2){u-v-w , u+v-2w , u+w} and for each group she created a matrix with each row representing a vector(before the zero column). so if the matrix is independent its means the same for the group of vectors?.  i am quite new in linear algebra so sorry if i am asking obvious questions.

Comment: What are u, v and w?

Comment: in the question its said "{u,v,w} is a linear independent group in Rn" and than "determine if the following groups are linearly independent".

Comment: So it's ok: a 3x3 matrix has linear independent rows if and only if its columns are linearly independent.

Comment: so group 2# is linearly independent cause it could be put into REF form and group 1# is dependent cause you could get zero's row? just making sure cause i am very new to this. thanks for the help

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, (u+3v-w)-2(v+w)=u+v-3w so this confirms that the first family is dependent.